# Should I ask foreign professors to become their volunteer research assistant (online)?

Tags: research-undergraduate

I am in need of some research experience, so I want to email some foreign professors whose work I'm genuinely interested in to ask if they can take me as research assistant (online). It is not a problem if it is unpaid because my goal is to get research experience for graduate application. I will do the job seriously because I need to cultivate necessary skills.

Is that a dumb thing to do? or is there any drawback?

Comment: What field are you in?

Comment: Do not volunteer to do work that should be paid. If you do that, you can out-compete local people looking for a job. It is also generally illegal to volunteer to do labor in a foreign country where a local would be employed and paid.

Comment: @BryanKrause im interested in econometrics

Comment: Echoing @AzorAhai-him- 's comment: there are ethical problems with volunteering to do work that someone else might want, and need, to get paid for. That is, you'd be offering yourself at a wage that would undercut other peoples' living-wage aspirations, for sure. I realize that this would be accidental, but it's a real thing, and in some parts of the world is actually illegal, apart from having ethical problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Volunteer research assistant" is a problematic term. It sounds like something I should be asking HR about before I could agree to anything, and you being overseas would make things even messier. "Research assistant" is a job title, and being one might make you a member of the hosting university. Not asking for money means that no funding is needed, but this doesn't necessarily make the paperwork any easier. Also, some (many?) people feel that it is unethical to volunteer for something others would expect to get paid for.

In my eyes, it is a completely different picture if instead you seek to collaborate with a researcher on a particular project. This wouldn't put you in any kind of hierarchical structure, and being an independent researcher is a perfectly valid hobby.

The second issue is the question what you can actually offer. Most opportunities where inexperienced people can contribute well are in-person tasks (cleaning laboratory equipement seems to be a popular task to give to students seeking research experience). In my area (math/TCS), it would be very difficult for someone lacking experience to make any positive contribution, and accepting to work with a stranger would make little sense to me. Whether you have something to offer will depend both on your current skills, and on what exactly people in your area do in their research.

Comment: I completely agree with that. "Unpaid research assistant" -> hard no from me. "Collaborate with me online" -> potentially yes (but I will have many questions).

Answer (score 3):

It is not a dumb thing to do from your end.  You aim to seek knowledge and improve yourself, especially when you are in an environment that lacks such opportunities.  This is admirable.

The drawback is that you are unlikely to get a reply or an 'honest' reply, meaning someone that seeks to exploit you may reply.

In general, professors will not reply because they will not spend the time on a student who is not enrolled in their institution.  Another reason: such a student may run off with their idea(s).  Further, you could be a scammer.  Nowadays we receive many unsolicited messages that aim to pilfer private information.